# Output of the tricky 'for' loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Consider:

```
for(var i=5; i%2==1?i=1:i++ && i<10; i++){
    console.log(i);
}
```

How does the value of `i` increment when `i` is assigned 1 every time the `for` loop runs?

#### Output

```
1 3 5 7 9
```

Comment: It is assigned 5, not 1 - and 1 when i is odd

Comment: Exactly the same as for `(var i = 1; i < 10; i += 2) {`

Answer (score 2):

Here's what happens in a single iteration:

1. the stopping condition is evaluated. if `i` was odd, it's now 1, otherwise it is incremented. If `i` is now greater or equal to 10 the loop stops.
2. the loop's body is executed and `i` is printed
3. the loop's "final expression" ([that's what MDN calls it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#syntax) at least) is executed and `i` is incremented

The first iteration you're assigning 1 to `i` and printing it, then incrementing `i` to 2.
The second time `i` is not odd, so it's incremented and 3 is printed, then you increment `i` to 4, which still isn't odd and this carries on printing odd numbers until it reaches 9.

Comment: Thanks, I just missed something in understanding. @Aaron

Comment: @Prashant you're welcome ! Consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer if it solved your problem (or adding your own and accepting it if you think there's more to it).